# Failed to install oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

I'm new to Oracle database. I'm trying to install the 12c version, on Windows 64, but I'm getting the error shown in the picture

[image]

I've already searched for this error on Google, but there is no related topics. Does anyone know how to solve this problem please ? Thank you

Comment: Are you an administrator on this machine?

Comment: yes. I have only one user on this machine and I can run applications as administrator is this what "being administrator on a machine"

Comment: Some information can be found there: 
 http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html (... maybe you need another user account for this ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be an issue with a missing group in the Windows Local Groups folder.

Please ensure you have the following groups in your Computer Management (compmgmt.msc). Open up the relevant branches to reach the **Groups** branch:

```
Computer Management
    System
        Local Users and Groups
            Groups
```

Not all groups are required. The groups marked with an asterisk <sup>*)</sup> should be available in English even though your OS is French (or a different language) as it can cause issues. The groups marked with a <sup>+)</sup> should be there in any case.

- Administrators <sup>*)</sup>
- ORA_ADMADMIN
- ORA_ASMDBA
- ORA_ASMOPER
- ORA_CLIENT_LISTENERS
- ora_dba <sup>+)</sup>
- ORA_DBSVCACCTS
- ORA_GRID_LISTENERS
- ORA_INSTALL
- ORA_OPER
- ORA_OraDB12Home1_DBA
- ORA_OraDB12Home1_OPER
- ORA_OraDB12Home1_SYSBACKUP
- ORA_OraDB12Home1_SYSDG
- ORA_OraDB12Home1_SYSKM
- USERS <sup>+)</sup>

If you can't manually create the groups marked with <sup>*)</sup> and <sup>+)</sup> yourself, then you don't have enough privileges and should run the installation with a privileged or escalated ("RunAs Administrator...") account.

*Depending on what you wish to achieve, you would also possibly need to add certain Window accounts to the individual Window groups. E.g. you might need to add `your_account` as a member of the `ora_admin` group.*

### Reference Material

- Bug 17846528 CONNECTIONS THROUGH LISTENER HANG AFTER 2049 ATTEMPTS ON NON-ENGLISH SERVERS (Oracle Support)
  **Solution:** Create a local "Administrators" group
  <sup>*(Oracle Support Account required to read bug article)*</sup>